# Getting an Error when calling a child variable from a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Hello and thanks for taking the time to look into my question.

I had an earlier question and Jesse Altman was kind enough to give me a great response.

I am using Force IDE and the salesfore.schema to find the appropriate variables, but I am getting an 'Invalid foreign key relationship Opportunity.service_contracts__r.

This is my code:

```
for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new){
        if(opp.StageName == 'PO In (100%)' && opp.Service_Contracts__r.size == 0){

        }
      }
```

This is my schema:

[image: The opportunity Child Relationship schema]

I must be missing something, and I do not know how I can test this.

Thanks again for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops. It should be `opp.Service_Contracts__r.size()`

I missed the parentheses in my other post. Apparently Salesforce doesn't give you a very good error message for this situation.

Also, just as quick warning, you may need to load the list from the database (if you notice it always coming back as null). I can't remember now if the list is populated in a trigger context or not.

Comment: Thanks Jesse! I will try it out tomorrow morning, as I have just gotten home and cannot change the network security.
What do you mean by load the list?

Comment: Related objects (either parent or child) are *not* populated in Trigger.new/old. Best practice would be to do a "collect" step with the initial for loop to get only the records you want to work with, make the DB trip with SOQL, then go back for the child records with a second loop.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will do just that. With this loop though I wouldnt then be calling opp.Service_Contracts__r.size() correct? Just the list created by the for loop?

Comment: @Peter I couldn't remember if they were populated or not. Good to know!

Comment: @jnoel10 - I updated my original answer on your original question to show the more correct code - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8341/is-using-a-class-a-good-option-for-creating-a-new-object-and-how-could-i-send-an/

Comment: I am still getting stuck with this, I have added Quotes as well( I can ask this in a new question) within my opportunity select i added (SELECT id, etc FROM quotes) FROM Opportunity .. But getting the Invalid foreign key relationship Opportunity.quotes

Comment: Do i just need to keep it to the opportunity select and then make a new list of quotes where the opp.id = to my other opportunity list?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't pulling in the right object name. That should work, but I don't know. Check out the Force.com Workbench - https://workbench.developerforce.com/ - Log into your Sandbox, API 27 > Jump to - Standard & Custom Objects > Opportunity. Check Child Relationships. Look for Quote and then click it. It should show you the RelationshipName. The RelationshipName is what you need in your nested query. I hope all of that makes sense.